# конвертирования таблицы

Tags: sql, oracle

у мене есть  список товаров и  пользователи купившие товар, нужно вывести пользователей и товары, которые они не купили

товар:

| ID |
| --- |
| x |
| y |
| z |

пользователи купившие товар

| ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 1 | y |
| 1 | z |
| 2 | x |
| 2 | y |
| 3 | z |

ожидаю увидеть

| ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | z |
| 3 | x |
| 3 | y |

Comment: Обычный CROSS JOIN + NOT EXISTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM users
CROSS JOIN products
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM purchases
                   WHERE purchases.user = users.user
                     AND purchases.product = products.product )
```